# Dart null / false / empty checking: How to write this shorter?

Tags: if-statement, dart, conditional-statements

This is my code for true on everything but empty string, null and false:

```
if (routeinfo["no_route"] == "" || routeinfo["no_route"] == null || routeinfo["no_route"] == false) {
    // do sth ...
}
```

This is my code for true on everything but empty string, null, false or zero:

```
if (routeinfo["no_route"] == "" || routeinfo["no_route"] == null || routeinfo["no_route"] == false || routeinfo["no_route"] == 0) {
    // do sth...
}
```

How can I write this shorter in Dart? Or is it not possible?

Comment: Is there a typo in your question? By `routeinfo["no_route"] != false` you mean `routeinfo["no_route"] == false`, right?

Comment: Yeah right edited. Bit tired its late ;-)

Comment: You could design your application in a way that a key will only be there if there is a truthy value to it, so you can just check for the presence of the key and trust it. Maybe it's impossible design it that way (depending on the context), but it's worth trying.

Answer (score 224, accepted):

If your requirement was simply empty or null (like mine when I saw this title in a search result), you can use Dart's safe navigation operator to make it a bit more terse:

```
if (routeinfo["no_route"]?.isEmpty ?? true) {
  // 
}
```

Where

- `isEmpty` checks for an empty String, but if routeinfo is `null` you can't call isEmpty on null, so we check for null with
- `?.` [safe navigation operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_navigation_operator) which will only call isEmpty when the object is not null and produce null otherwise. So we just need to check for null with
- `??` [null coalescing operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator)

If your map is a nullable type then you have to safely navigate that:

```
if (routeinfo?["no_route"]?.isEmpty ?? true) {
  //
}
```

Comment: Interesting syntax  Can you explain it a bit more in detail what role of the questionmarks is? The classical elvis is `?:` right?

Comment: @Blackbam - updated the answer with some explanations

Comment: Another nice way to write this: `if ((value ?? '') == '') { ... }`

Comment: best answer. $0.02 - this is the way it should be done unless there's a specific reason not to

Comment: 1.) The expression `myString?.isEmpty ?? true` is a "nullable expression", and if your `if` statement has more than one condition (like the OP's example), each nullable expression must be wrapped in parenthesis, which is annoying and decreases readability.  2.) Syntactic sugar is great, but most of us write code that others also have to read, use, maintain, etc. Unless some drastic performance increase would be recognized with a more complex solution, it is usually best to go with the simple solution that everyone will understand. In this case that is `myString != null && myString.isNotEmpty`.

Comment: @ubiquibacon agreed. As I said, if your requirement is simply empty or null then this answer is good. If, like the OP your requirement is more complex, there are better answers here. Including your suggestion.

Comment: Interesting answer. But as much as it looks short, it adds extra cognitive complexity and is more difficult to read than a simple null check followed by an empty check.
In the end, readability should be prioritized over small optimization(often unnecessary)

Comment: @SaurabhKumar I'm glad you find the answer interesting, but that was not my intent. I was aiming to give a *shorter* expression as the OP asked. Good point about readability, though.

Answer (score 73):

You could do

```
if (["", null, false, 0].contains(routeinfo["no_route"])) {
  // do sth
}
```

Comment: Getting error: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: @Kamlesh - lowercase null? not in quotes? (i.e. null, not Null or 'null')

Comment: Kindly suggest me what is difference null, Null and NULL? Thanks

Comment: Creating a mutable data structure for an empty string check?!  In general, this is very bad practice, but is especially bad practice when you consider that Dart's primary function in this world is as a language for mobile devices (i.e. embedded systems) with limited memory and processing power.  Please don't do this!

Answer (score 45):

## Late 2020 Update

#### Summary

- This answer holds true, except for `isNull` and `isNotNull`. They no longer provide type promotion when `Null Safety` is introduced in dart/flutter in the future.
- Other helpers like `isNullOrEmpty` do not provide type promotion, as they are in a different (sub-)scope compared to callsite.
- My personal opinion, is that you can drop `isNull` and `isNotNull` but keep other helpers as you shouldn't expect them to do type promotion for you.

#### Explanation

- This is because `Null Safety` was finally introduced in Dart/Flutter. But as of October 2020, this feature is still not available for stable releases on dart/flutter. Check out the quick guide [Null Safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety) or the thorough [Understanding Null Safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety).
- Null Safety in Dart/Flutter should be similar to Swift ([Optional](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional)) and Kotlin ([Nullable Types, Non-Nullable Types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html)).

#### Demonstration

**Here's a demonstration why encapsulation/helper-getter of `isNull` (`== null`) and `isNotNull` (`!= null`) is a very big problem:**

```dart
// Promotion works
int definitelyInt(int? aNullableInt) {
  if (aNullableInt == null) { // Promote variable `aNullableInt` of Nullable type `int?` to Non-Nullable type `int`
    return 0;
  }
  return aNullableInt; // Can't be null! This variable is promoted to non-nullable type `int`
}
```

When "Null Safety" is shipped in the dart release you are using, the type promotion in above code works! HOWEVER:

```dart
// Promotion does NOT work!!!
int definitelyInt(int? aNullableInt) {
  if (aNullableInt.isNull) { // does NOT promote variable `aNullableInt` of Nullable type `int?`
    return 0;
  }
  return aNullableInt; // This variable is still of type `int?`!!!
}
```

The above doesn't work, because the null check `== null` and `!= null` are encapsulated in a sub-scope (different stack frame) and not inferred to have this "promotion" effect within `definitelyInt` scope.

---

---

## Early 2020 Update

Here's a modified version using **getters** instead of **instance/class methods** and covering **whitespaces**, **isNull**, and **isNotNull**.

#### Second Update

It also accounts for empty lists and maps now!

#### Third Update

Added private getters for safety and modularity/maintainability.

#### Fourth Update

Updated the answer to fix a particular problem with `Map`, it's not correctly being handled when empty! Because `Map` is not an `Iterable`. Solved this issue by introducing `_isMapObjectEmpty` U

### Solution

```dart
extension TextUtilsStringExtension on String {
  /// Returns true if string is:
  /// - null
  /// - empty
  /// - whitespace string.
  ///
  /// Characters considered "whitespace" are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59826129/10830091).
  bool get isNullEmptyOrWhitespace =>
      this == null || this.isEmpty || this.trim().isEmpty;
}

/// - [isNullOrEmpty], [isNullEmptyOrFalse], [isNullEmptyZeroOrFalse] are from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59826129/10830091)
extension GeneralUtilsObjectExtension on Object {
  /// Returns true if object is:
  /// - null `Object`
  bool get isNull => this == null;

  /// Returns true if object is NOT:
  /// - null `Object`
  bool get isNotNull => this != null;

  /// Returns true if object is:
  /// - null `Object`
  /// - empty `String`s
  /// - empty `Iterable` (list, set, ...)
  /// - empty `Map`
  bool get isNullOrEmpty =>
      isNull ||
      _isStringObjectEmpty ||
      _isIterableObjectEmpty ||
      _isMapObjectEmpty;

  /// Returns true if object is:
  /// - null `Object`
  /// - empty `String`
  /// - empty `Iterable` (list, map, set, ...)
  /// - false `bool`
  bool get isNullEmptyOrFalse =>
      isNull ||
      _isStringObjectEmpty ||
      _isIterableObjectEmpty ||
      _isMapObjectEmpty ||
      _isBoolObjectFalse;

  /// Returns true if object is:
  /// - null `Object`
  /// - empty `String`
  /// - empty `Iterable` (list, map, set, ...)
  /// - false `bool`
  /// - zero `num`
  bool get isNullEmptyFalseOrZero =>
      isNull ||
      _isStringObjectEmpty ||
      _isIterableObjectEmpty ||
      _isMapObjectEmpty ||
      _isBoolObjectFalse ||
      _isNumObjectZero;

  // ------- PRIVATE EXTENSION HELPERS -------
  /// **Private helper**
  ///
  /// If `String` object, return String's method `isEmpty`
  ///
  /// Otherwise return `false` to not affect logical-OR expression. As `false` denotes undefined or N/A since object is not `String`
  bool get _isStringObjectEmpty =>
      (this is String) ? (this as String).isEmpty : false;

  /// **Private helper**
  ///
  /// If `Iterable` object, return Iterable's method `isEmpty`
  ///
  /// Otherwise return `false` to not affect logical-OR expression. As `false` denotes undefined or N/A since object is not `Iterable`
  bool get _isIterableObjectEmpty =>
      (this is Iterable) ? (this as Iterable).isEmpty : false;

  /// **Private helper**
  ///
  /// If `Map` object, return Map's method `isEmpty`
  ///
  /// Otherwise return `false` to not affect logical-OR expression. As `false` denotes undefined or N/A since object is not `Map`
  bool get _isMapObjectEmpty => (this is Map) ? (this as Map).isEmpty : false;

  /// **Private helper**
  ///
  /// If `bool` object, return `isFalse` expression
  ///
  /// Otherwise return `false` to not affect logical-OR expression. As `false` denotes undefined or N/A since object is not `bool`
  bool get _isBoolObjectFalse =>
      (this is bool) ? (this as bool) == false : false;

  /// **Private helper**
  ///
  /// If `num` object, return `isZero` expression
  ///
  /// Otherwise return `false` to not affect logical-OR expression. As `false` denotes undefined or N/A since object is not `num`
  bool get _isNumObjectZero => (this is num) ? (this as num) == 0 : false;
}
```

### Assumptions

This presumes Dart 2.7 or above to support [Extension Methods](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods).

### Usage

The above are two Extension classes. One for `Object` and one for `String`. Put them in a file separately/together and import the files/file at callsite file.

### Description

Coming from Swift, I tend to use extensions like user @Benjamin Menrad's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59562423/10830091) but with getter instead of method/function when applicable -- mirroring Dart's computed properties like `String.isEmpty`.

Coming from C#, I like their String's helper method [IsNullOrWhiteSpace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=netcore-3.1).

My version merges the above two concepts.

### Naming

Rename the Extension classes whatever you like. I tend to name them like this:

> **XY**Extension

Where:

- **X** is File/Author/App/Unique name.
- **Y** is name of Type being extended.

Name examples:

- `MyAppIntExtension`
- `DartDoubleExtension`
- `TextUtilsStringExtension`
- `OHProviderExtension`

### Criticism

> Why private getters instead of simple
> `this == null || this == '' || this == [] || this == 0 || !this`

- I think this is safer as it first casts the object to the right type we want to compare its value to.
- More modular as changes are central within the private getters and any modification is reflected everywhere.
- If type check fails within the private getter, we return false which doesn't affect the outcome of the root logical-OR expression.

Comment: Fixed checking collections if they were empty or not with private getter `_isObjectIterableEmpty`

Comment: Fixed another issue where `map` is not handled. I presumed it was a `Literal`, apparently it's not! Fixed is introduced with `_isMapObjectEmpty` private getter.

Comment: You will not want to use `.isNull` or `isNotNull` in the future. With null safety, you can promote a nullable variable no non-nullable with a `== null` check, but not with `.isNull`. That makes `isNull` and `isNotNull` a dangerous habit to get into.

Comment: This is bad. I updated my answer accordingly. Your comment was confusing back in June, when I revisited today I got what you mean and explained it for others..

Comment: With null-safety, your extension should be on `String?` instead of `String`

Comment: Thanks @Arash, I will update my answer for the newest flutter and dart versions and inform you here in comments when I'm done.

Answer (score 30):

I would write a helper function instead of doing everything inline.

```
bool isNullEmptyOrFalse(Object o) =>
  o == null || false == o || "" == o;

bool isNullEmptyFalseOrZero(Object o) =>
  o == null || false == o || 0 == o || "" == o;
```

That avoids the repeated lookup (like the `contains` operation), but it is much more readable. It also doesn't create a new `List` literal for each check (making the list const could fix that).

```
if (isNullEmptyOrFalse(routeinfo["no_route"])) { ... }
```

When struggling with making something short and readable, making a well-named helper function is usually the best solution.

(Addition: Now that Dart has extension methods, it's possible to add the functionality as methods or getters that are seemingly on the object, so you can write `value.isNullOrEmpty` directly).

Comment: Modified the answer to add support for whitespace. Also check my full modified answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59826129/10830091).

Comment: the lambda function worked great. bool isNullEmptyOrZero(Object o) =>
  o == null || false == o || "" == o || 0==o;  I added a check for 0 to exclude

Answer (score 16):

As coming from Android and Kotlin, I prefer extension methods over a static helper method. And with Dart 2.7 you can now use that as well:

```
extension Extension on Object {
  bool isNullOrEmpty() => this == null || this == '';

  bool isNullEmptyOrFalse() => this == null || this == '' || !this;

  bool isNullEmptyZeroOrFalse() =>
      this == null || this == '' || !this || this == 0;
}
```

Now you can just call these methods from anywhere in your code:

```
if (anyVariable.isNullOrEmpty()) {
  // do something here
}
```

You might need to manually import the dart class, where you put your extension methods, for example:

```
import 'package:sampleproject/utils/extensions.dart';
```

Comment: the import get removed by android studio, probably it cannot detect the usage of it. any idea to work around it?

Comment: With "null safety" enabled (in Dart 2.12 beta), using one of the extension method proposed (e.g. `isNullOrEmpty`), on a nullable object leads to the error: `An expression whose value can be 'null' must be null-checked before it can be dereferenced.`.

Comment: if(testvariable == null){} condition does not work. Getting VSCode suggestion - The operand can't be null, so the condition is always false.
Try removing the condition, an enclosing condition, or the whole conditional statement

Answer (score 5):

#### With Null safety:

Say, you have a nullable `Map` and a `List` which have nullable values in it.

```dart
Map<String, List?>? map;
List<String?>? list;
```

To check if the collection is neither `null` nor empty, you can do:

```dart
if (map?.containsKey('foo') ?? false) {
  print('map is not-null, and key "foo" is present.');
}

if (list?.isNotEmpty ?? false) {
  print('list is not-null and not empty');
}
```

Comment: It looks terrible. Is it possible to write some extension func that works well with Null safety?

Answer (score 4):

For strings i like this approach:

```
extension NullableStringExtensions<E> on String? {
  /// Returns `true` if this string is `null` or empty.
  bool get isNullOrEmpty {
    return this?.isEmpty ?? true;
  }

  /// Returns `true` if this string is not `null` and not empty.
  bool get isNotNullNorEmpty {
    return this?.isNotEmpty ?? false;
  }
}
```

Credits go to the author of this package: https://pub.dev/packages/string_ext

Answer (score 2):

```
bool isNullString(String? value) {
      if (value == null || value.isEmpty ) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

and use this method like

```
isNullString(yourValue)
```

Comment: OK other than the `value == false` check; a condition which is not possible since `value` was declared as `String?`.  Additionally, you can shorten this by getting rid of the `if/else` and simply returning `return value == null || value.isEmpty`

Answer (score 2):

You can do an extension like this so you can use it everywhere:

```
extension StringExtensions on String? {
  bool isNullOrEmpty() {
    return this == null || this == "";
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`package:quiver`](https://pub.dev/packages/quiver) has an [`isEmpty`](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.strings/isEmpty.html) function that returns `true` if the argument is `null` or the empty string.

It's also trivial to implement such a function yourself.

Answer (score 0):

check for not null and not empty

```
if (routeinfo["no_route"]?.isNotEmpty == true) {
  // 
}
```