# DECODE BASE64STRING TO IMAGE IN FLUTTER

Tags: node.js, flutter, listview, base64, uint8list

this my code to display image

```
body: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: jsonList == null ? 0 : jsonList.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ListTile(
          leading:Image(image: MemoryImage(base64Decode(base64String))),
          trailing: Text(jsonList[index]['pname']
            ,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.brown, fontSize: 15),
          ),
          title: Text(jsonList[index]['pdesc']),
        );
      }),
```

but end up with this error
I/flutter (15439): FormatException: Invalid length, must be multiple of four (at character 256)
I/flutter (15439): ...2vt6b997q855/zhVdW9337r3dgewn+fll6e607fqVJ3z/Z3z209deIfeof+fSfytO1CEBCfeR+0
I/flutter (15439):

anybody please help me?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63941130/base64invalid-length-must-be-multiple-of-four-error-in-flutter

Comment: cant reproduce your issue, can you provide any example img?

Comment: this is an image that i already encode to base64
I/flutter (28015): iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGAAAABgCAYAAADimHc4AAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAIABJREFUeJztnXmYHVWd9z/nVN2lt3R30p3urIQkhCSQEMISdjCIEEZREYbNDcdxXubl9cGRxdFBZdwQlRl1RHnAEXVEUV9FUXYxISQhZCH7TrbO2vt6b997q855/zhVdW9337r3dgewn+fll6e607fqVJ3z/Z3z209deIfeof+fSfytO1CEBCfeR+0

Comment: @Mayati please edit your question to add the Base64 string. The string in the comment above seems to be truncated due to the character limit in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base64String is wrong, try another and it should work for you. I'll send you an example.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List jsonList = [
      {"pname": "test", "pdesc": "example"}
    ];

    //String base64String =
    //    "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGAAAABgCAYAAADimHc4AAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAIABJREFUeJztnXmYHVWd9z/nVN2lt3R30p3urIQkhCSQEMISdjCIEEZREYbNDcdxXubl9cGRxdFBZdwQlRl1RHnAEXVEUV9FUXYxISQhZCH7TrbO2vt6b997q855/zhVdW9337r3dgewn+fll6e607fqVJ3z/Z3z209deIfeof+fSfytO1CEBCfeR+0";
    String base64String =
        "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";
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Material App Bar'),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: jsonList.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                leading: Image(image: MemoryImage(base64Decode(base64String))),
                trailing: Text(
                  jsonList[index]['pname'],
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.brown, fontSize: 15),
                ),
                title: Text(jsonList[index]['pdesc']),
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: *The base64String is wrong* - The string that was posted in the comments is probably not really wrong but just truncated due to the character limit in comments.

Comment: Exactly, your comment had not appeared when I posted :). thanks. But if it is wrong, it is either because it is cut or because the last character is missing, which is most likely,
add "=" and work

"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGAAAABgCAYAAADimHc4AAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAIABJREFUeJztnXmYHVWd9z/nVN2lt3R30p3urIQkhCSQEMISdjCIEEZREYbNDcdxXubl9cGRxdFBZdwQlRl1RHnAEXVEUV9FUXYxISQhZCH7TrbO2vt6b997q855/zhVdW9337r3dgewn+fll6e607fqVJ3z/Z3z209deIfeof+fSfytO1CEBCfeR+0="

Comment: you are right franklin....thank you so muchhhhh