# if (value.isEmpty) isEmpty is not working how i fix this

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to fix using ?. and !. and !! none of them is working

And error message is The property 'isEmpty' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').

```
    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.**isEmpty**) {
          setState(() {
            errors.add("Please enter your email");
          });
        }
        return null;
      },
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Email",
        hintText: "Enter your email",
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        suffixIcon: CustomSurffixIcon(
          svgIcon: "assets/icons/Mail.svg",
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: simply just use `if(value!) ` and [safe-null](https://dart.dev/null-safety)

Answer (score 0):

If you call

```
if(value.isEmpty)
```

and value is null, what condition will be checked?
Try

```
if(value != null && value.isEmpty)
```

Or see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52948927/5619109

```
if(value?.isEmpty ?? true)
```

Comment: all of them not working :'(

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use [Flutter Form](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation)

Create a function like this, customize it for yourself, just like above.

```dart
  String? _validateInput(String? value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Please enter some text';
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Then use this function to validate, like

```dart
return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      validator: _validateInput,
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Email",
        hintText: "Enter your email",
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        suffixIcon: CustomSurffixIcon(
          svgIcon: "assets/icons/Mail.svg",
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's work for me

```
value == null || value.isEmpty
```

Or

```
value!.isEmpty
```