# List Index Null Safety Check - RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Tags: list, flutter, dart, null, dart-null-safety

I have read many posts on here and none seem to answer my question directly. I have a call to build a watermarked photo if the `postAssets` is `notEmpty` and contains specific image files. I also have an `else` statement for when the list is empty or has a different file type in there. However, I am having issues with running the null-safety check on the list if the list is null. The `assetIndex` is being passed to the widget as an `int`.

```
class ShareMenuWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ShareMenuWidget({
    Key key,
    this.assetIndex,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final int assetIndex;

  @override
  _ShareMenuWidgetState createState() => _ShareMenuWidgetState();
}

class _ShareMenuWidgetState extends State<ShareMenuWidget> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
```

Relevant code is

```
RaisedButton(
 onPressed: () async {
//this is the line throwing the error if postAssets is empty or null
 final assetUrl = containerPostsRecord.postAssets.elementAt(widget.assetIndex);
  if (containerPostsRecord.postAssets.isNotEmpty &&
 assetUrl.contains('jpg') || assetUrl.contains('png') || assetUrl.contains('gif') || 
 assetUrl.contains('jpeg') || assetUrl.contains('webp') || assetUrl.contains('bpm'))
  {
    final newImage = Function 1
  }
else {
   final newImage = Function 2
  }
},
```

When I run this, I get the following error

```
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
```

I could probably do this with multiple `if` statements, but is there anyway to check for null in the `assetUrl` declaration within the `postAssets` list?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to check before using the value. Something like this:

```
final assetUrl = containerPostsRecord.postAssets.contains(widget.assetIndex) ? containerPostsRecord.postAssets.elementAt(widget.assetIndex) : '';
```

Comment: I tried something similar `final assetUrl = containerPostsRecord.postAssets.elementAt(widget.assetIndex) ?? '';` but it still gave me the same error. I am still learning Flutter syntax, but is that equivalent to what you suggested?

Comment: It would be equivalent if `containerPostsRecord.postAssets` has the index your are  sending (index in range) and it's value is null, but if not it will throw error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try {
 doSomething();
} on RangeError catch (_) {
 handleException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a null or empty check on the `postAssets` list before you start the code. And you can always add more checks up front, like if the index is within range at all, even when it is not an empty list.

```dart
if (containerPostsRecord.postAssets?.isEmpty ?? true) {
    return; // or throw?
}

// do the rest of your code.
```

Used this from the example shown in this answer:

[Dart null / false / empty checking: How to write this shorter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42446566/dart-null-false-empty-checking-how-to-write-this-shorter)